# NativeScript autocomplete data from remote server

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am following [this](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/professional-ui-components/ng-AutoCompleteTextView/aync-data) link to get autocomplete data from remote server.

I use NativeScript with Angular. Here are my changes to given code returns me

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'jsonUrl' of
>   undefined ;

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonUrl = 'mycustomerurl';
    let that = this;
    let options = this.createRequestHeader();
    this.autocomplete.autoCompleteTextView.loadSuggestionsAsync = function (text) {
        const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          http.request({
            url: this.jsonUrl + '/' + text,
            method: "GET",
            headers: options,
           }).then(function (r: any) {
                let d = r.content;
                alert(r.content.length); // Undefined
                console.error(d); // Data exists
                alert(d.length); // Undefined
                const items: Array<TokenModel> = new Array();
                for (let i = 0; i < d.length; i++) { // Not going inside loop.
                    items.push(new TokenModel(d[i].label, null));
                }
                resolve(items);
            }).catch((err) => {
                const message = 'Error fetching remote data from ' + that.jsonUrl + ': ' + err.message;
                console.log(message);
                alert(message);
                reject();
            });
        });

        return promise;
    };

  }

private createRequestHeader() {
    // set headers here e.g.
    const tokenInfo = appSettings.getString('TokenInfo');
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenInfo}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
     });

    return headers;
  }
```

I get remote in below format from my url https://mysite/api/SearchName/rk where rk is user text for filter from remote.

```
[
    {
        "label": "GLOBAL AGENCIES LTD",
        "id": "P000003",
    "val": "100.00"
    },
    {
        "label": "NEW MARKETING LTD",
        "id": "P000004",
    "val": "200.00"
    }
]
```

On User selecting a label, I want to perform some operation with its "id" and "val".

What else am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` will not be pointing to your component when `loadSugfestionsAsync` function is called. Use a arrow function to retain the context or simply use `that.jsonUrl` which is already holding reference to context.

Comment: If I add that.jsonUrl, http request working. Next error is that r.content.length is undefined however console.error(r.content); shows data.

Comment: Of course content is an object, it doesn't have a property called length. Please refer the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/http) carefully.

Comment: ok, adding r.content.toJSON(); is working. Now, 1. Content displays up to 6 items and rest ideally should be scrolled but not working.  2. On user typing 2nd char onwards, autocomplete shows 'no records found'